# Why does my scale variable not adjust after a button click in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, loops, bitmap

The method `genereer` ("generate") draws a Bitmap image of a Mandelbrot. It has a variable `schaal` ("scale") which makes the Bitmap zoom in on the image with a certain factor. The standard value for this is 0.01, as declared above in the partial class Form1.

I have a `textBox3` in the GUI, and I want to be able to type a new value in this `textBox3`, click on the button and draw a new image based on the scale.

I've written a method called `Lees` ("read"), which parses a double from `textBox3`. I've put this method in the `Button1_MouseClick` method, as well as the `genereer` method to draw a new image upon button click. I've also put the `genereer` method in the `Form1_Shown` method.

However, this doesn't seem to be working. When I click on the button, no matter what the value is, I get a white dot in the middle of the screen.

```cs
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public double waardeX, waardeY, schaal = 0.01;
        public int maxIteraties;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {        
            Genereer();
        }

        public void Lees()
        {
            schaal = double.Parse(textBox3.Text);
        }

        private void Genereer()
        {
            double max = 100;
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(Figuur.Width, Figuur.Height);
            for (int x = 0; x < Figuur.Width; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < Figuur.Height; y++)
                {
                    //double a = (double)(x - (Figuur.Width / 2)) / (double)(Figuur.Width / 4);
                    //double b = (double)(y - (Figuur.Height / 2)) / (double)(Figuur.Height / 4);
                    double a = (double)(x - (Figuur.Width / 2)) * (double)(schaal);
                    double b = (double)(y - (Figuur.Height /2)) * (double)(schaal);
                    Mandelgetal getal = new Mandelgetal(a, b);
                    Mandelgetal waarde = new Mandelgetal(0, 0);

                    int i = 0;
                    while (i < max)
                    {
                        //i++; //v1
                        waarde.Vermenigvuldig();
                        waarde.Toevoegen(getal);

                        if (waarde.Wortel() > 2.0)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (i % 2.0 == 0.0)
                            {
                                bitmap.SetPixel(x, y, Color.White);
                                i++; //v2
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                bitmap.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Black);
                                i++; //v2
                            }
                        } 
                    }
                    if((a*a + b*b) > 4)
                    {
                        bitmap.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Black);
                    }
                    Figuur.Image = bitmap;                    
                }
            }
        }

        private void Button1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Lees();
            Genereer();
            this.Invalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: **[Using the free, built-in Step Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)** to debug your own code is easier than you think

Comment: @EdPlunkett I still get a strange white dot in the middle of the circle when I do that, it doesn't deliver the correct image, even when I scale it back to the standard value 0.01.

Comment: Can you add images of what you get and what you expect?